# error validating data: ValidationError(CronJob.spec.jobTemplate.spec.template.spec): unknown field "replicas" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.PodSpec

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I want to define replicas in my cron job

```
spec:
schedule: "5 15 * * 1-5"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      parallelism: 1
      template:
        metadata:
          annotations:
            rollme: {{ randAlphaNum 5 | quote }}
        spec:
          replicas: 1
          containers:
          - name: daily-automation
```

but getting error

Answer (score 1):

job.spec.template.spec must be valid Kubernetes [Pod specification](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.19/#jobspec-v1-batch). A Pod is a single set of containers and does not possess any concept of `replicas` in its specification.

Replica counts are exposed by some higher level abstractions which create Pods like Deployments & ReplicaSets.

If you are trying to make the job trigger multiple Pods simultaneously, you will want to set `parallelism` and `completions` in accordance with your desired behavior: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/#parallel-jobs .